# How mobx.autorun() knows which observables you access?

Tags: mobx

I'm purely curious (high level explanation) how mobx.autorun() is smart enough to grovel through the function it's passed to determine which observables are accessed?

Comment: I think [**this blog post**](https://medium.com/@mweststrate/becoming-fully-reactive-an-in-depth-explanation-of-mobservable-55995262a254) from the creator of MobX is a great explanation of how it works.

Answer (score 3):

The short story is that `autorun` does not parse your code looking for usages, but rather records each access of an observable within the first run. This is why it must run once straight away.

It has wrapped the [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and [setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) of each observable so that it can record which ones you use (via the getter) and build a list of observables that your autorun function used. If any of them change (via the setter), it will detect that and rerun your autorun function.